# Nested for loops in Python

Tags: python, loops

I want to do something like

```
for a in [0..1]:
    for b in [0..1]:
        for c in [0..1]:
            do something
```

But, I might have 15 different variables.  Is there a simpler way like

```
for a, b, c in [0..1]:
    do something
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for a,b,c in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=3):
  # do something
```

Comment: My only complaint is it took so long for you to answer.  There was a period of about 30 seconds where I was in limbo.

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the product of all of them. Use itertools.product and pass in your ranges.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.product(range(2), range(3), range(2)):
print (i)
```

yields

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 2, 0)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1) 
(1, 2, 0)
(1, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a matrix/list of variables you need to process.  Thus, the best (and speediest) solution is to use a matrix/list tool.

Such as: The Python `itertools` package.

As other have hinted, `itertools.product` is probably what you want.  But, see the full list at:
http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html

Good luck.