# Python multiple for loops

Tags: python

I am wondering if the 3 for loops in the following code can be written in a better way:

```
   Nc = 10     # number of points for (0, pi)
   cc1 = linspace(0,pi,Nc)
   cc2 = linspace(0,pi/2,Nc/2)
   cc3 = linspace(0,pi/2,Nc/2)
   for c1 in cc1:
       for c2 in cc2:
           for c3 in cc3:
               print c1,c2,c3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested for loops in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164162/nested-for-loops-in-python)

Comment: it is not a duplicate. The answer based on `numpy.meshgrid()` or similar is not appropriate for the other question.

Comment: related: [itertools product speed up](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4709510/4279)

Comment: Better in what way?  Faster?  More memory efficient?  Prettier?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
import itertools

for a,b,c in itertools.product(cc1, cc2, cc3):
    print a,b,c
```

Comment: Should be : print( (a,b,c)

Comment: This is Python 2.

Answer (score 7):

try this :)

```
[(c1, c2, c3) for c1 in cc1 for c2 in cc2 for c3 in cc3]
```