# Python: Iterate over a sub-2d (nested) array to calculate its sum

Tags: python, lambda

I want to realize this function: calculate the average value(or the sum) `rgb` value of an image. More specifically, the image consists of an 2-d array of a tuple. Here is my code:

```
rgb = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
for r in range(0, 3):
    for ii in range(x, x + X_STEP):
        for jj in range(y, y + Y_STEP):
            rgb[r] += src_pix[ii][jj][r]
rgb = map(lambda a: a / X_STEP / Y_STEP, rgb) #this line does not matter, it is just the difference between sum and average
```

**Question** How to prettify it, or make it more pythonic? Maybe a nested `map` is still not the best. I hope it is like using `itertools`.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164162/nested-for-loops-in-python) provides a solution close to my question. Another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713150/sum-of-2d-array-in-python) is a possible duplicate of my code but he is not asking the same question.

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**
I actually hope to calculate the sum of a sub 2-d array.

Comment: Do you want the average value or the sum?  They're not the same.

Comment: I think they're the same except for the last line of my code which is a divide operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using PIL.  If so I'd use numpy for this.

Assuming you are using PIL version >= 1.1.6 , you can convert between the PIL object `src_pix` to numpy array like so:

```
np_pix = numpy.array(srx_pix)
```

Then just use `numpy.sum` :

```
rgb = numpy.sum(np_pix)
```

Or calculate the average (as your code above does):

```
rgb = numpy.mean(np_pix)
```

For older versions of PIL use `numpy.asarray`.

If you want to compute the sum of a subarray, you can get that subarray using a *slice* like so:

```
rgb_slice = numpy.mean(np_pix[X_start:X_end,Y_start:Y_end])
```

**References**:

- [PIL and numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384759/pil-and-numpy) (older SO
  post on this topic)
- [Scipy Documentation on Array Manipulation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: Does it provide such functionality to calculate the sum of a sub 2-d array?

Comment: Yeah - just do np_pix[X_start:X_end,Y_start:Y_end] to get the subarray you want.